# [[ Coding in AWK ]]

Tags: regex, awk

Firstable:

1. This is my first time to write a only AWK code.
2. My background is BASH thinking.
3. My aim is to figure out the AWK thinking to start writing down my own AWK codes.

So, I was wondering how to write an AWK code that:

1. Replaces `\n_ _ _` with `;_` (Each `_` is a white space).
2. Finds a pattern and only print all the lines with that pattern.
3. Replace each semicolon with `\nC1 \[` and at the end of the preceding line to newline, close it with `]`.
4. Update the preceding line with the next line complementary info.
5. Comparing patterns among the last word of each line with an external file with country names list in it.

So far I have done is (This only covers till third line):

```
awk '
    {gsub(/\n   /,"; ")} 
    /^C1 \[/ 
    {gsub(/; /,"\nC1 ")}
    ' file
```

Thank so much in advance for any clue.

Comment: I create a file `File 2` with a country names list, with those into

Comment: Read fifth step at intro

Comment: One problem is that `awk` reads lines, so `$0` will never contain blanks after a newline.  You can use `/^   /` to search for three blanks at the beginning of a line, but you've already printed the previous line.  This suggests that you'll need to accumulate input lines for processing.  Or you'll need to get fancier with the pattern used to detect end of record (RS).

Comment: Thank so much @JonathanLeffler and yes, I'm towards to learn how to accumulate input lines, like in bash coding, but in awk coding (only, if possible). My reason is that definitely awk is the fastest language on handling big data files and I want to learn it. The big 'but' is that I'm trying to write an awk code thinking in bash. Of course, the answer is think in awk, but to me is something like start thinking in french ... First I see the structure, otherwise I'll be choked, like starting virgin with french. Thanks so much : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, normal awk code assumes processing line by line. Indeed, without additional command line options awk removes all `"\n"`. So your attempt to replace `"\n   "` with `"; "` doesn't make much sense since your code will never see "\n".

To merge multiple lines into one you can use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
/^[AC]\w/ {
            printf "\n%s",$0
            next
        }
/^\s/ {
            printf " %s",$0
            next
        }
```

The above code says that when it encounters a line starting with `A` or `C` followed by a word character (for example `U` or `1` or `i`) then print a newline followed by the line. And when it encounters a line starting with a space character (space or tab) then print the line without a newline.

Of course, there are small problems with this. For example it prints a newline at the beginning of the output and no newline at the end. And it also does not strip the leading spaces for the lines that start with spaces. But we'll leave it at this for now.

This answers the question to your first step question.

But that's not what you want. What you want is to normalize the `C1` values. So first let's write code that ignores everything except `C1` values:

```
/^C1/ {print}
```

OK now we need to handle all the tabbed lines that belong to `C1` so we need to modify our code a bit:

```
BEGIN {c1_found=0}

/^C1/ {
        c1_found=1
        print
        next
    }

/^\s/ {
        if (c1_found == 1) {
            print "C1 " $0
        }
        next
    }

    {
        c1_found = 0
    }
```

So. We create a variable `c1_found` to flag that we are in a `C1` block. We initialize it in the BEGIN block to 0 and set it to 1 when we encounter a C1 block. Now whenever we see a line that starts with spaces we check if we are in a `C1` block and print that line by appending `"C1 "` in front of it.

Now we want to handle the normalization. This is the difficult bit. Let's write a function for that since it's going to be called in two places:

```
function normalize (c1_line) {
    split(c1_line,a,"[[]]")
    c1 = a[1]
    names = a[2]
    location = a[3]

    split(names,b,";")

    for (nam in b) {
        print c1 b[nam] location
    }
}
```

This function first splits its input by `[` or `]` which breaks the line up into its three component sections. Then it splits the second section by `;`. Finally it iterates over the names and prints one line for each.

Now lets include this into our code:

```
function normalize (c1_line) {
    split(c1_line,a,"[[]]")
    c1 = a[1]
    names = a[2]
    location = a[3]

    split(names,b,";")

    for (nam in b) {
        print c1 b[nam] location
    }
}

BEGIN {c1_found=0}

/^C1/ {
        c1_found=1
        normalize($0)
        next
    }

/^\s/ {
        if (c1_found == 1) {
            normalize("C1 " $0)
        }
        next
    }

    {
        c1_found = 0
    }
```

The code above generates file1. Now, to generate file2 the easy way out is to write another script that prints only country names and then pipe them through `sort` and `uniq` (or `sort -u` if your sort can do that). However, if you insist on doing it in awk you can (in fact it's quite simple and readable). First we use an associative array to keep track of all countries that appears:

```
function normalize (c1_line) {
    split(c1_line,a,"[[]]")
    c1 = a[1]
    names = a[2]
    location = a[3]

    split(names,b,";")

    for (nam in b) {
        print c1 b[nam] location
    }
    countries[$NF] = 1
}
```

Then we just print the countries array into a file:

```
END {
    for (c in countries) {
        print c >> file2.txt
    }
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to assemble the full program. But as you can see, programming in awk is quite different compared to bash or pascal of C or perl or assembly. It's more like programming in regexp - in that awk has a built-in loop that constantly scans the input and execute code when a match is found.

So, as an example, the following program:

```
BEGIN {print "starting"}
/^mango/ {print "ha"}
/^monkey/ {print $0}
END {print "done"}
```

is exactly identical to:

```
/^monkey/ {print $0}
END {print "done"}
BEGIN {print "starting"}
/^mango/ {print "ha"}
```

There is a subtle difference when the matches are substrings of each other. For example when you want to trigger `/^HEL/` separately from `/^HELLO/`. But in general execution doesn't read linearly from the top down.

Also, be warned that awk only has global variables. So use good variable names to avoid overwriting some other variable elsewhere.

Comment: Remember that in a function you can create 'local' names by `function funcname(arg1, arg2,     local1, local2, local3)` (normally written with multiple spaces separating `arg1, arg2` from `local1, local2, local3` is an informal indication that the unused arguments are effectively local variables.  But that's only within a function; other variables are indeed effectively global.

Comment: Thank so much slebetman and @JonathanLeffler for your advises, have a good day :D

Comment: Fixed a bug I found in the array iterations. I forgot that `for x in y` gives the index rather than the values.